# How to fix overflow exception from visual basic 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am new to visual basic. I am developing a project in visual basic 2019 for my mini project.I wanted to creat a simple table.I have typed the following code but, each time i enter the values into the form and press submit I get the exception as "overflow" in a message box . I couldn't able to find out the reason for this. Please help me out.

The following is the code:

```
Dim Liste_des_clients As New DataTable

Private Sub Btnsuivant_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnsuivant.Click
    With Liste_des_clients
        .Columns.Add("Nom", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("Prénom", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("CIN", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
        .Columns.Add("Date de Naissance", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    End With

    Dim newrow As DataRow = Liste_des_clients.NewRow
    newrow("Nom") = "Rebgui"
    newrow("Prénom") = "Imad"
    newrow("CIN") = "BN415269"
    newrow("Date de Naissance") = "10/12/2001"
    Liste_des_clients.Rows.Add(newrow)
    Dim newrow1 As DataRow = Liste_des_clients.NewRow
    newrow1("Nom") = "Majidi"
    newrow1("Prénom") = "Naser"
    newrow1("CIN") = "BK256398"
    newrow1("Date de Naissance") = "10/12/1988"
    Liste_des_clients.Rows.Add(newrow1)

    Dim newrow2 As DataRow = Liste_des_clients.NewRow
    newrow2("Nom") = "Rachad"
    newrow2("Prénom") = "Nouha"
    newrow2("CIN") = "BF789654"
    newrow2("Date de Naissance") = "14/02/2000"
    Liste_des_clients.Rows.Add(newrow2)


    If Tbxcin.Text = "BN415269" Or Tbxcin.Text = "BK256398" Or Tbxcin.Text = "BF789654" Then

        MsgBox("Vous étes déjà inscrit")
    Else
        Dim newrow3 As DataRow = Liste_des_clients.NewRow
        newrow3("Nom") = Tbxnom.Text
        newrow3("Prénom") = Tbxprénom.Text
        newrow3("CIN") = Tbxcin.Text
        newrow3("Date de Naissance") = Tbxdate.Text
        Liste_des_clients.Rows.Add(newrow3)
        MsgBox("Bien Enregistrer")
        Me.Hide()
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include in which line the exception occurs.

Comment: its the first line

Comment: This line? `Dim Liste_des_clients As New DataTable`?

Comment: yes this line: Dim Liste_des_clients As New DataTable

Comment: could you post the whole code file?

Comment: this is the whole code for the form 1 in my project.and it consists of three forms but the problem is in this code

Comment: Is Btnsuivant the submit button?

Comment: yes its the submit button to show the form 2

Comment: If the stackoverflow is happening on the first line, I would think your issue is further up the chain, perhaps even how you're creating and/or calling the instance of that form.  Any chance of seeing the calling code?

Comment: Looking at the code you have posted the line you say has the exception can't have an exception as written.  I ran your code as a standalone and it did not fail.

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help I appreciate it. I tried to use another code and it work for me now